# .net: Do you prefer populating a datatable when retrieving data from database or populating a generic list of your own custom object?

Tags: .net, datatable, populate, generic-list

which senario do you prefer when you're retrieving data from database?

1 - Populating a datatable and then bind a datagridview to it?

OR

2- populating a genric list of your own custom object and then bind a datagridview to it?

Thank you

Comment: sounds subjective - I would recommend re-phrasing to discuss the *merits* of each, rather than just "preference".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 2 - list of objects :-)

reasons (or as marc notes, 'merits'):

- lighter weight
- ability to extend the list via custom
  class
- potential to use filters/linq to
  objects in a fashion that are better
  suited to business objects
- DataTables are Microsoft specific. If you need to pass them into a non-Microsoft, i.e. Java web service you will need to create a separate business object to pass to it.
- check out current OR/m implementations - not many datatables going on there..
- if it's a web project, then keeping
  the connection open whilst reading
  the results into the datareader is a
  bit of a no-no
- DataTables almost beg the developer to place the business logic in the user interface layer. Having a business rules region in a business object woos the coder into placing the business rules in the proper place.
- unit testing of your results - far
  easier in a custom class defined via
  an interface
- strong typing of properties (rather
  than string indexes against the
  datatable 'fields')

also, using DataTables directly means tying yourself to the underlying data source and how that is structured. From a maintainability point of view, this isn't a good idea. If all your view needs is a list of some objects, that's all you should be giving it (i.e. a list).

**[edit]** - it's an old article, but is worth adding to the 'debate':

*When considering DataSets vs. business objects, remember that a well designed application using business objects will reduce future headaches in the maintenance of the application which ultimately lead to lower support costs.*

http://www.kellermansoftware.com/t-articlebusinessobjects.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I would not suggest working with db directly at all. There're nice ORMs: LINQ to SQL, Entity Framework and NHibernate. Who needs old painful datatables ?